# MS Access on moveable forms / Having a form in it's own window not constrained to the application

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a question that should be quick and easy for you guys to answer.
My application has ~25 forms that by default are in their own windows and not constrained to the ms access tabs. One particular form I made is opened in a tab view, stuck to the ms access window. What property (or necessary code on the form load/open event) is necessary to have this form as a seperate window, not stuck to ms access (and preferably with the minimize/maximize buttons at the top right. Here are my properties:

[image: Properties for this form]

I will also note that it doesn't allow me to change the 'moveable' option to yes.
It is a pain when all of my other forms open in a seperate window and this one is hiding attached to MS Access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the `pop up` property which is found on the `other` tab.

Comment: Bingo, I don't know how I glazed over it. It's been a long day. +1 and accepting when I can, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks worked for me for my Access 2007 database.
Interestingly on a different Access 2003 format database (opened in Access 2007) I was comparing it to , moveable is set to yes and 'Pop Up' is set to no, but the window is detached.

Thanks

Kristian